# Using the auto increment id from one query as the fk of the next insert

Tags: mysql, php, transaction, insert, auto-increment

I'm not sure if I'm overcomplicating this or whether I can't see the wood for the trees.

I have two tables, both have auto incrementing ID's.

```
Table 1:
ID - auto
field - int
other field - varchar

Table 2:
ID - auto
Table1Id - FK
field - varchar
```

the first table stores an article and the 2nd stores the location of the images related to it.

For my form that uploads the data all information to be stored is taken.  I need to run two inserts simultaneously (which I realise is daft) using the same ID.

My plan(flawed) is to insert into table 1, get the id and then insert into table 2.

one of the problems if is a user accesses the site in the gap between the two inserts and sees a mess.

is there an easier way, I think I've made a mistake or I'm missing something obvious as it shouldn't be this difficult. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (in part) where transactions come in.
Assuming your transaction isolation level is "read committed", "repeatable read" or "serializable" (MySQL defaults to "Repeatable read" and anyone setting it to lower than "read committed" is committing crimes against the laws of the universe), other transaction are blind (to some extent) to changes made within your transaction.

So you should:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT #1;
INSERT #2;
COMMIT;
```

The other transactions will not be able to read your first INSERTed row (though they can find trace of its existence via locks -- probably not interesting to you). They will only be able to read both your changes or none of them.

This, again, depends on the assumption that these transactions don't come from a connection with "Read committed" isolation level -- which, unfortunately -- is something anyone is able to change for their own connection.

Comment: I thought a transaction wouldn't be suitable because I need the ID from one insert to use in the other and the ID won't have been generated until the commit?

Comment: In theory I'd need to start trans, insert into table a, get ID from table a, insert into table b, commit?

Comment: @SteveGreen - yes, the flow you describe is correct, and will work just fine within the scope of a transaction.

Comment: ah, then I thank you and thank you again.  I thought that the ID would not be available until the commit had taken place.

Comment: np. best, as always, is to give it a try and see...

Comment: Shlomi, I don't suppose you use PDO do you?  I have two functions in two classes for the inserts. each has a try and catch.  I'm not sure if this is now considered bad practice to try and tie these together within the transaction.

Comment: I do not use PDO. With Java, for example, I would use Springs JdbcTemplate, which allows for a transaction block of code. Otherwise I'm not sure how this works for you.

Comment: no problem, I jsut attmepted it, closed my eyes and......fail :)

Catchable fatal error: Object of class article could not be converted to string in c:/blabalbalbabla

now trying to figure it out.

Comment: <3 Java :) php too :)

Comment: fantastic! works really well once I sroted out the php issue